# MongoDB Aggregation - Joining two collections with only specific information from second collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am learning MongoDB Aggregation and have been going back and forth with the problem below. I have two collections, modeled as the following:

```json
Contacts
{ 
_id: ObjectId('2341908342'),
fName: Test,
lName: TestTwo,
companyId: "61f4147b8415abfc04d09207",
},
{ 
_id: ObjectId('2341908342'),
fName: John,
lName: Doe,
companyId: "62847a16ee5c5047820415d2",
}

Companies
{
_id: ObjectId('61f4147b8415abfc04d09207'),
companyName: "Facebook",
domain: "www.facebook.com",
}
{
_id: ObjectId('62847a16ee5c5047820415d2'),
companyName: "Google",
domain: "www.Google.com",
}
```

I am trying to write an aggregation function that will grab all of the Contacts, then match the companyId between the Contacts and the Companies, and project the data as such:

```
Contacts 
{
_id: ObjectId('2341908342'),
fName: Test,
lName: TestTwo,
companyId: "61f4147b8415abfc04d09207",
companyName: "Facebook",
domain: "www.facebook.com",
}
```

As of right now, I am doing this as so in Typescript:

```
   await allContactsCursor.forEach((contact: any) => {
      if (contact.companyId) {
        const company = allCompanies.find(
          (co) => co._id.toString() === contact.companyId,
        )
        if (company) {
          allContactsCursor.push({
            ...contact,
            companyName: company.companyName,
            domain: company.domain,
          })
        } else {
          allContactsCursor.push(contact)
        }
      } else {
        allContactsCursor.push(contact)
      }
    })
```

But would like to do this through Aggregation. I am still learning Aggregation, but here is what I have so far:

```js
try {
    const allContactsCursor = await contactsCollection
      .aggregate([
        {
          $match: {
            orgId: {
              $in: [new ObjectId(req.user.orgId)],
            },
          },
        },
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: "companies",
            let: {
              companyId: {
                $toString: "$_id",
              },
            },
            pipeline: [
              {
                $match: {
                  $expr: {
                    $eq: ["$companyId", "$$companyId"],
                  },
                },
              },
            ],
            as: "companyName",
          },
        },
      ])
      .toArray()
```

I know this is incorrect, but I imagine I need to compare Company ID's, then write a $project after this to get my companyName and domain fields added. However, I am not sure, or even sure if this is possible. Thank you for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `$unwind` to handle the `$lookup` result array and use `$mergeObjects` and `$replaceRoot` to wrangle the result to your expected form.

```js
db.Contacts.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "Companies",
      "let": {
        companyId: "$companyId"
      },
      "pipeline": [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $eq: [
                "$$companyId",
                {
                  $toString: "$_id"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "companyLookup"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$companyLookup"
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": {
        "$mergeObjects": [
          "$$ROOT",
          {
            companyId: "$companyLookup.companyId",
            companyName: "$companyLookup.companyName"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unset: "companyLookup"
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/wZkkucPtROH)

A side note: consider refactor your schema to keep the data type consistent. i.e. companyId should be either ObjectId or string in both collections.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. For the collections they actually have much more fields than what I gave above. I am trying to understand your solution, how can I only push the companyName and domain to the Contacts collection without all of the extra data? I hope this makes sense. Thank you.

Comment: @CameronWood23 updated the answer. Just keep the fields you needed in `companyLookup` when doing the `$mergeObjects` would be fine.

Comment: That is amazing and it worked, thank you. Now time for me to study how you did it! Haha

Comment: If you go inside my playground link, you should be able to see "Stage by stage output" at the top bar. This could help you to view the pipeline stages and the output of each stages.